# How can i find the presence of email address in whole database tables in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, email

I have 1GB mysql database. This is my company database and i have to re-factor the whole site and database.

I have changed the email address in user table but there are still some tables where email address is stored as text in some fields like html data but i don't know

Is there any way to find email pattern in all database tables and replace only that part

Comment: Take a look at the 'LIKE' operator inside SQL. But be warned: that is gonna be extremey slow and will create a huge load on the server. Try to narrow possible occurances down as fa as possible.

Comment: `select yourfield from yourtable where yourfield like '%@%'` would be a very quick/ugly filter to at least find only those records which MAY contain an email address.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to find anything that *might* be an email address, check out the `RLIKE` operator so you can use a regular expression like `\b\S+\@\S+\.\w+\b` to find them. It might be faster and more convenient to scan a `mysqldump` snapshot than the database itself.

Comment: Even if i do in the mysql dump , how will that change in database. ALso i have few tables with blob  field , where i have the email address , is there any way to replace the email address in blob fields keeping everything same

Comment: you dump the dump back into the database. `mysql -u username -ppassword database_name < dump.sql`

Comment: You can dump, fix, and restore if you want, something that's practical if you can endure a small amount of down-time. Barring that, at least you know where you need to change things.